# Can't edit last two characters in HTML text input

Tags: javascript, html

I'll start by saying that I have no idea why this is happening, and that just yesterday it was working just fine. I have this input (it gets saved on the Onblur event), and I can edit everything in the input except the final two characters or numbers in any field. It is though that is fixed for some reason. I don't seem to recall this happening before this morning. So I'm expecting Rod Serling to come in at any moment and inform me that I am in fact in the twilight zone. I've switched back to any earlier commit, when I new it was working, and for some reason the problem persists. (Even after a hard refresh and flushing content just in case JS is stale). Everything else works, on blur the values are saved correctly, it's just the simple fact that I CAN'T CHANGE THE LAST TWO CHARACTERS IN THE INPUT FIELD!!! (sorry, it was a late night)

EDIT: Sorry, I should state that it starts out like this:

```
<td onclick="addInput(this);" id="website_revenue:2017-03-16">$479,432.00</td>
```

And the input is added just fine.
If the value in the input is this:

```
<input type="text" id="input:website_revenue:2017-03-06" value="$479,432.00" />
```

I can't edit the "00".

I first thought, maybe it's a decimal issue, but I can't edit the last two characters in a whole number:

```
<input type="text" id="input:website_revenue:2017-03-06" value="360">
```

In that case I can't edit the "60".

Maybe it's my entire lack of sleep, but I've never seen anything like this before in my 15 years of programming...and I have NO IDEA why it's happening. No clues in the console, no errors are being flagged. Any ideas? Am I in the twilight zone??

Here is the JS being used, which again, worked just fine yesterday:

```
function addInput(elm) {
  if (elm.getElementsByTagName('input').length > 0) return;

  var value = elm.innerHTML;
  elm.innerHTML = '';

  var id = elm.getAttribute('id');

  if(value == "$0.00" || value == "0"){
    value = "";
  }

  var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
  input.setAttribute('id', 'input:'+id);
  input.setAttribute('value', value);
  input.setAttribute('style', 'width:100px;');
  input.setAttribute('onBlur', 'closeInput(this)');
  elm.appendChild(input);
  input.focus();
}

function closeInput(elm) {
  var td = elm.parentNode;
  var value = elm.value;

  td.removeChild(elm);

  if(value == ""){
     td.innerHTML = "0";
  }else{  

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/pages/process.php",
    data: "edit_data="+elm.id+"&value="+value,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(ret){
      if(ret.success === true){
         td.innerHTML = ret.value;

         if(ret.math === true){
           var targets = ret.targets;

           for (i in targets){
              for (key in targets[i]){
                if(key == "key"){
                  var newid = targets[i][key];
                }

                if(key == "value"){
                  var newval = Math.round(targets[i][key]);
                  var elm = document.getElementById(newid);
                  elm.innerHTML = newval;
                }
              }
           }

         }
      }else{
         $("#error").html("ERROR: These fields can only accept numbers!!");
         td.innerHTML = "ERROR";
      }
    }

  });

 } 
}
```

Comment: You don't have to use `.setAttribute()` and `getAttribute()` generally - the DOM makes standard attributes available as properties. Thus, `elm.id` is the "id" value, `elm.value` is the "value", etc.

Comment: Anyway what exactly do you mean by "edit"? Are you saying that you cannot interactively change the last part of the value when you focus into the `<input>` element?

Comment: Can you reproduce in a JS fiddle?

Comment: Correct. I can't delete them at all. I can add other numbers or letters to the field, but those two are never changed.

Comment: Another thing: that loop in the ajax "success" handler is really fragile. There's no guarantee that you'll see the "key" property before the "value" property, as there's no ordering guarantee for JavaScript object properties.

Comment: Do you have a global JS file that is acting on all input boxes? Perhaps another dev wrote something that globally affects inputs.

Comment: Thanks @pointy, but that entire event happens after my problem exists, so it is unrelated to my issue. It hasn't given me an issue so far.

Comment: Perhaps, @nibblypig. I'll inspect the diffs on recent commits.

Comment: Try setting size attribute of the input

Comment: Ok, so I think I figured it out in github from a diff. The only real change was in CSS. The input seems to be inheriting a recent change to the div that contains the table, that sets the scroll from right to left (direction:rtl;), this set the cursor all the way to the right, and for some reason, that creates this issue. If I set the input itself to direction:ltr; the problem is fixed. So I wonder then, why does direction:rtl ruin the input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I think I figured it out in github from a diff. The only real change was in CSS. The input seems to be inheriting a recent change to the div that contains the table, that sets the scroll from right to left (direction:rtl;), this set the cursor all the way to the right, and for some reason, that creates this issue. If I set the input itself to direction:ltr; the problem is fixed.

So I wonder, why does direction:rtl ruin the input?